# How to subset a data frame based on a column of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

(Updated) I have dataframe1 that looks like:

```
  A C D E F
1 c f x i e
2 d g i d d
3 e h p e e
```

and dataframe2:

```
  A B
1 c q
2 d m
```

Noted that dataframe2$A is a subset of dataframe1$A. How do I subset dataframe1 based on column A of dataframe2, and add ONLY column C of dataframe1 to dataframe2? I hope to get:

```
  A B C
1 c q f
2 d m g
```

Comment: What do you mean by "subset dataframe1 based on column A of dataframe2"? If `dataframe2$A` had been "c, z" instead, would you just want the c-row of `dataframe1`? Or is it always true that `dataframe2$A` is a subset of `dataframe1$A`?

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)` in base R, `inner_join(df1, df2)` in `dplyr`.

Comment: `merge(df1,df2,all.y=T)` or even `merge(df1,df2)`

Comment: Hi @AaronMontgomery Yes, dataframe2$A is a subset of dataframe1$A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inner_join` from dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(A = c("c", "d", "e"),
           C = c("f", "g", "h"))

df2 <- data.frame(A = c("c", "d"),
                  B = c("q", "m"))

inner_join(df1, df2)
#> Joining, by = "A"
#> Warning: Column `A` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
#> character vector
#>   A C B
#> 1 c f q
#> 2 d g m
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I updated the answer with inner_join